# How do I set background images of table cells in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I am currently statically setting background images in my dynamic sap.m.table through CSS. However, I want to set my background images in Javascript and not CSS. For instance, given an array of images like this:

```
 var imgArray = imageUrl1, imageUrl2, imageUrl3, imageUrl4.
```

I want to loop through the array and assign the cells of my table to the imageUrls.

I'm currently doing something like this in CSS:

```
.sapMListTblCell:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/cute-baby-tabby-short-hair-260nw-160585535.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Here is a link to a jsbin depicting how I am creating the table: https://jsbin.com/huyiyofexu/edit?html,css,js,output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this, but I recommend creating a 2d array from your table, then iterating over it doing whatever logic you like based off row and col nums:

```js
const bgs = [
  ["red", "green", "blue"],
  ["magenta", "yellow", "cyan"],
  ["black", "gray", "white"]
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const myTable = document.getElementById("MyTable");
  
  const trs = Array.from(myTable.querySelectorAll("tr"));
  const grid = trs.map((tr) => {
    const tds = Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll("td"));
    return tds;
  }); 


  grid.forEach((row, rowNum) => {
    row.forEach((tdElement, colNum) => {
      tdElement.style.background = bgs[rowNum][colNum];
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="MyTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1-1</td>
    <td>1-2</td>
    <td>1-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2-1</td>
    <td>2-2</td>
    <td>2-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3-1</td>
    <td>3-2</td>
    <td>3-3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```